# Uncaught SyntaxError when trying to reading csv data

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp, mootools

I am using Mootools JSONP to read from an url which returns a CSV file. Now one of the columns in the CSV (Adj Close) has a blank space which aborts the reading of the file and throws out the error onto the console. What are my options, if any, to read the csv data?

I am getting the error:

> table.csv:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

One more additional information:  I can see the csv file getting downloaded to the browser.  Can I not read it from the browser?

```js
var url = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GOOG&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=31&f=2010&g=w&ignore=.csv';

  loaderJSONP(url);

loaderJSONP = function(URL) {
  //Get Data
  new Request.JSONP({
    url: URL,
    onSuccess: function(response) {
      show_response(response, $('post'));
    }
  }).send();

  show_response = function(obj, result) {
    console.log(obj);
  };
}
```

Comment: You need quotes around your URL for one

Comment: My bad...made the edit to the question.  Thanks for pointing the typo

Comment: That url is not returning a JSONP string, its returning a csv file

Comment: I agree.  I am looking for workaround if any to either load the csv file or pre-process the output to json.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Do you have a server-side also in this app? Like @Tim Wienk suggested in Github... That way you could convert the data in the server side and then request it with JSON between the app and the server.

Comment: I do have a server side to it. But I was hoping to either do it completely on the client side or embed a php etc. script into the html that can be called to do the trick.  Appreciate a demo or any form of documentation that you may have.  The idea is to avoid client sever client I/O to speed up the app performance as the transfer of heavy historical price data from server to the client can potentially create some performance issue

Comment: Is that data static/historical? or its data that needs to be updated?

Comment: It is end of day data so it is static for that given 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the [answer I gave on GitHub](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/issues/1343) here, for future reference:

> The idea of JSONP is that the resource returns "JSON with Padding", where the JSON is a value in JavaScript Object Notation, and the Padding is a function call, with as aim to get around same-origin policies.
>
> - JSON: `{"a":"b"}`
> - JSONP: `myCallbackFunction({"a":"b"})`
>
> So basically, the JSONP resource is expected to return valid, executable JavaScript code, and you (or in this case MooTools More) provide(s) the definition of "myCallbackFunction". The resource location is then appended with `&callback=myCallbackFunction` and injected as `src` of an HTML `<script>` tag. The tag is injected into the document, and the function is called with the data supplied, so you can go about your things. (The function itself won't be called "myCallbackFunction" by MooTools, in case you're wondering.)
>
> The resource you request from ichart.yahoo.com returns a CSV format and I doubt that it supports any callback function padding, meaning it probably can't work this way.
>
> I can see two options:
>
> 1. Look at [Yahoo's developer console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/), see if the `yahoo.finance.historicaldata` table suits your needs, or if there is another way to fetch your data through YQL.
> 2. Fetch the CSV through other means (some server), and supply it back to your application (with optional pre parsing, so you don't have to parse the CSV in JavaScript).

Answer to follow-up question, regarding option 2, about why there were no results:

> You'll have to use the callback value passed as query parameter.
>
> Try something like this (untested):
>
> ```
> function print_json($data) {
>     $json = json_encode($data);
>
>     if (array_key_exists('callback', $_GET) && !preg_match('/[^\w.]/', $_GET['callback'])) {
>         header('Content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');
>         echo $_GET['callback'], '(', $json, ')';
>     } else {
>         header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
>         echo $json;
>     }
> }
> ```